# How to compile arm32 code on an x86 machine for an aarch64 target

Tags: compilation, cross-compiling, cpu-architecture, yocto

I want to run a code written for raspberry pi (arm32). The current host system for the code is x86 based and I want to compile a binary for the target system (aarch64). What is the best way to approach this problem?

I am expecting the arm32 code to be compiled on x86 and run on aarch64.
I am not able to compile on the target system (aarch64) itself as it is a yocto build and I cannot find a straight path to install a toolchain for it.

Comment: Many ARMv8 CPUs can run in AArch32 state at least for user-space, so you can build your ARM32 source into 32-bit ARM binaries and run them on an RPi, unless its CPU only supports AArch64 mode.  You won't find a tool that automatically translates ARM32 code to ARM64, not that I know of.